# Масштабирование canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Создаю небольшой графический редактор на js.Использую библиотеку fabric.js. Вопрос таков: возможно ли сделать отдаление и приближение canvasa, то есть чтобы можно отдалить и приблизить всю картинку. Такое есть в любом графическом редакторе. В интернете не нашёл ничего подобного на js, только FLASH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У fabric.Canvas есть методы getZoom и setZoom именно для этого

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzoygc4/1/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var url = "http://serio.piiym.net/CVBla/txtboard/thumb/1260285874089s.jpg";
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (img){
    img.left = 80;
    img.top = 50;
    canvas.add(img);
});
canvas.renderAll();
alert(canvas.getZoom());
canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom()*2);
canvas.renderAll();
alert(canvas.getZoom());
```